# Dictionary Serialization DeSerialization Issue

Tags: c#, json, rest, openrasta

I am using `OpenRasta` framework for `REST API` implementation. I have field in class which is of the type `Dictionary<string, string>` .I am testing this using REST Console(Google Chrome Plugin). After GET request to resource it gives me response in following format.

```
<CustomCheckBoxes>
        <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <d2p1:Key>Check1</d2p1:Key>
            <d2p1:Value>1</d2p1:Value>
        </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
</CustomCheckBoxes>
```

But when i use same XML for POST request on same resource while deserializing in XmlDataContractCodec it gives exception **There was an error deserializing the object of type Resource . The prefix 'd2p1' is not defined**

I have a specific requirement for the field i mentioned so i am using dictionary for it.Are there any alternative ways to serialize/deserialize Dictionary ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If only that namespace is unknown to the serializer, you could try to remove it before passing it to the deserializer.

Like `s/d2p1://g`.

Comment: I tried removing it but then nothing gets serialize.I get 0 items at server side.

Comment: Only remove it in that string that you feed the **de**serializer, keep all the rest unchanged. Like `deserializer.Deserialize(xmlString.Replace("d2p1:", ""))`.